Issues with VS Code Live Server and Chrome
I use Google Chrome as my default browser and every time I check my code on the Live Server lately, an extra box appears at the bottom of my work. When the html is exported, it looks fine and when I try to load the code on another browser, it also works perfectly. Is this a chrome error? I've updated the Chrome browser and still get an extra box at the bottom of the live server.
Original HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <section></section>
        <section class="bigSection"></section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
    </html>

Original CSS
/* Box Model */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}

header, footer {
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
clear: both;
}

section{
  height: 300px;
  width: 20%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
}
.bigSection{
  width: 40%;
}

Here's the live code: HTML of Live Source (http://127.0.0.1:5500/template/index.html)
    <html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: circular;

  src: url('chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/fonts/CircularXXWeb-Book.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: circular;

  src: url('chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/fonts/CircularXXWeb-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}</style></head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <section></section>
        <section class="bigSection"></section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
        <footer></footer>
    <!-- Code injected by live-server -->
<script>
    // <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
        (function () {
            function refreshCSS() {
                var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
                    var elem = sheets[i];
                    var parent = elem.parentElement || head;
                    parent.removeChild(elem);
                    var rel = elem.rel;
                    if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") {
                        var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, '');
                        elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf());
                    }
                    parent.appendChild(elem);
                }
            }
            var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://';
            var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws';
            var socket = new WebSocket(address);
            socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
                if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload();
                else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS();
            };
            if (sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer')) {
                console.log('Live reload enabled.');
                sessionStorage.setItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer', true);
            }
        })();
    }
    else {
        console.error('Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading.');
    }
    // ]]>
</script>


<div id="loom-companion-mv3" ext-id="liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb"><section id="shadow-host-companion"></section></div></body></html>

As I mentioned above, I updated Chrome and this problem still occurs. If I use a server like Duck Duck Go or Safari, there are no issues and the code looks like it should.
